Kubernetes running pods are detected by docker ps command
I'm new to kubernetes and just started practicing, I have first installed docker and later k3s on my ubuntu machine. I have created a deployment for a simple go server, pod got created.
ubuntu@linuxk8-hyd:~$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
goserver-deployment-5ff56f8db9-qxkwj   1/1     Running   0          5h49m

I couldn't see those container using docker command
ubuntu@linuxk8-hyd:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

can someone explain me what's happening under the hood.
I have also checked container runtime, it is containerd,
ubuntu@linuxk8-hyd:~$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME          STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION        INTERNAL-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
linuxk8-hyd   Ready    control-plane,master   2d4h   v1.29.3+k3s1   10.218.131.104   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS   5.4.0-176-generic   containerd://1.7.11-k3s2

I have issued another command to check containers by using ctr commands which interact with containerd, but didn't give any output, again confused here
ubuntu@linuxk8-hyd:~$ sudo ctr  containers ls
CONTAINER    IMAGE    RUNTIME

ubuntu@linuxk8-hyd:~$ sudo docker inspect -f '{{ .HostConfig.Runtime }}' $(sudo docker ps -aq)
runc
runc
runc

one more query is, If docker and k3s using same container runtime lets say containerd, can ctr command list all containers created from docker and kubernetes, in my case not, can someone help me here
one more query is, If docker and k3s using same container runtime lets say containerd, can ctr command list all containers created from docker and kubernetes, in my case not, can someone help me here

Kubernetes these days doesn't usually run Docker proper, but rather some other container engine.  Since you also can't usually directly log in to the worker nodes to run commands like docker or ps, this isn't usually relevant, and it certainly has no bearing on what you'd do as a developer.

probably,  you need something line this k3s crictl ps
